# How to access a specific element out of an array without iterating?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, gatsby-image

I have got the following folder structure

```
/images
/images/pic1.jpg
/images/pic2.jpg
```

When using the following GraphQL query..

```
query MyQuery1 {
  file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}, name: {eq: "pic1"}) {
    name
    publicURL
  }
}
```

The result can be accessed by using something like `<img src={data.file.publicUrl} alt="" />`. So far so good.

But now I would like to retrieve multiple images from that folder with a single query. So I came up with the following:

```
query {
  allFile(
    filter: {
      sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
      name: { in: ["pic1", "pic2"] }
    }
  ) {
    nodes {
      name
      publicURL
    }
  }
}
```

Great! But how I can now access one of those images without having to use `map` or iterate over the result?

I am looking for something like this, which of course doesn't work:

`<img src={data.file.publicUrl name.eq="pic1"} alt="pic1"/>`

Nor does somthing like this:

`<img src={data.allFile.nodes.0.publicUrl} alt="pic1" />`

I would like to use `gatsby-image` to optimize and resize my images. That's why I choose the GraphQL way over a direct import. Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I wasn't aware that one can *chain* things together. This worked for me.

```
query {
  imageOne: file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}, relativePath: {eq: "pic1.jpg"}) {
    id
    childImageSharp {
      fixed(width: 30) {
        base64
        tracedSVG
        aspectRatio
        width
        height
        src
        srcSet
        srcWebp
        srcSetWebp
        originalName
      }
    }
  }
  imageTwo: file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}, relativePath: {eq: "pic2.jpg"}) {
    id
    childImageSharp {
      fixed(width: 30) {
        base64
        tracedSVG
        aspectRatio
        width
        height
        src
        srcSet
        srcWebp
        srcSetWebp
        originalName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then later access it like so:

```
<Img fixed={data.imageOne.childImageSharp.fixed} alt="" />
```

and

```
<Img fixed={data.imageTwo.childImageSharp.fixed} alt="" />
```

P.S: This is the relvant part within `gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`, <<== gets filtered by sourceInstanceName: ..
    path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
```

Answer (score 1):

OP answered their own question but here is another way: Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const Index = (props) => {
  const { data: { allFile: { edges } } } = props;

  const heroImage = edges.filter
    (el => el.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalName === "heroImage.png")
      [0].node.childImageSharp.fluid;
  // ...
}

export const query = graphql`
{
  allFile(filter: {
    extension: {eq: "png"},
    sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}},
    sort: {fields: [childImageSharp___fluid___originalName], order: ASC})
  {
    edges {
      node {
      childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 300, quality: 50) {
            originalName
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```